# Sequelize: Aggregate on nested include (PostgreSQL)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

In my database, I have the following relevant tables: `users`, `listings`, and `reviews`

`users` have many `listings`

`listings` have many `reviews`

`reviews` has a column `value`, which is a float between 0 and 5.

I'd like to be able to come up with a rating for a user, which is defined as:

The average `value` of all `reviews` for `listings` owned by the user.

In Sequelize, I have this:

```
User.findById(userId, {
  include: [
    {
      model: Listing,
      order: [
        [Review, 'updatedAt', 'desc']
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: Review,
          include: [User]
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
})
```

This successfully gets me:

- All `user` fields
- All `listings` owned by the user
- All `reviews` for those `listings`

I do have enough information at this point to calculate the `user` average rating, but that's assuming that I never put any limit on the number of `listings` or `reviews` in this query. In order for the application to scale, I'll need limits, and so I have to be able to use aggregate functions to calculate the average rating on a `listing` and `user`.

I'm quite new to Sequelize and SQL in general. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?